# AutoMapper - Mapear uma coleção de strings para uma propriedade de uma coleção dentro de uma coleção

Tags: c#, automapper

**Qual a dúvida ?**

Como mapear IdContributors (coleção de strings) para uma coleção (Contributors), dentro da coleção TAction, com uma propriedade (ContributorId) de string, usando LINQ e autoMapper.

```cs
public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ActionViewModel, TAction>();
                //.ForMember(d => d.Contributors, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => ids = a.IdContributors.Select(x => { })));

        }
```

**Models**

**Model TAction**

```cs
public class TAction
    {
        public Guid Id {get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TActionContributor> Contributors { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
public class TActionContributor
    {
        public Guid TActionId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("TActionId")] 
        public TAction Action { get; set; }
        
        public string ContributorId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("ContributorId")] 
        public ApplicationUser Contributor { get; set; }
    }
```

**ActionViewModel**

```cs
public class ActionViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<string> IdContributors { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar instâncias de TActionContributor.

```
CreateMap<ActionViewModel, TAction>();
            .ForMember(d => d.Contributors, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => ids = a.IdContributors
            .Select(x => new TActionContributor(){ ContributorId = x })));
```